# Array of strings in groovy

Tags: arrays, string, groovy

In ruby, there is a indiom to create a array of strings like this:

```
names = %w( lucas Fred Mary )
```

Is there something like that in groovy?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Most of the time you would create a list in groovy rather than an array. You could do it like this:

```
names = ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"]
```

Alternately, if you did not want to quote everything like you did in the ruby example, you could do this:

```
names = "lucas Fred Mary".split()
```

Comment: But sometimes APIs require a String[], so providing both options in the answer would be nice.

Comment: Nice. I was actually looking to make an array, convert to list and then check if it contains a string, but I can skip the middle part by just creating the list directly and calling `contains()`. That's Groovy!

Answer (score 135):

If you really want to create an array rather than a list use either

```
String[] names = ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"]
```

or

```
def names = ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"].toArray()
```

Comment: or indeed ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"] as String[]

Comment: or `(String[])['Lucas', 'Fred', 'Mary']`

Comment: I think toArray() returns an Object[], not a String[].